# JavaScript error with dynamic buttons that open a Modal

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a sql query that returns an html table that includes first name, last name, empid and a dynamic button.  the following code creates the button.

```
echo '<td>
    <center>
        <button id="addemployee" class="add-employee-btn" data-firstname="'. $row[0] . '" data-lastname="'. $row[1] . '" data-empid="'. $row[2] . '">Add Employee</button>
    </center>
</td>';
```

I use the following Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Attach click event listener to a parent element of the "Add Employee" buttons
  $(document).on('click', '.add-employee-btn', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $(this).data('firstname');
    var lastName = $(this).data('lastname');
    var empId = $(this).data('empid');
    var modal = $('#addEmployeeModal'); // Get the modal element

    // Load the content from newemployee.php into the modal
    $('#modalContent', modal).load('../../newemployee.php', function() {
      // Set the values in the form fields
      $('input[name="FstName"]', modal).val(firstName);
      $('input[name="LstName"]', modal).val(lastName);
      $('input[name="EmpID"]', modal).val(empId);

      // Open the modal popup after the content is loaded
      modal.modal('show');
    });
  });

  // Clean up the modal content and reset form fields when the modal is hidden
  $(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#addEmployeeModal', function() {
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-content').empty();
    modal.find('form')[0].reset();
  });

  // Submit the form inside the modal
  $(document).on('submit', '#addEmployeeForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Perform AJAX request to add the employee
    // ...

    // Close the modal popup after submitting the form
    $('#addEmployeeModal').modal('hide');
  });

  // Add click event listener to the table rows
  $(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
    var persId = $(this).data('persid');
    var isCompleteMatch = $(this).data('completematch');

    if (isCompleteMatch) {
      window.location.href = '../../emp.php?persid=' + persId;
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

When the page loads, lets say there are rows in the table, I can click on any of the buttons and the Modal opens up with the right data being populated into the Modal.  When I close the Modal and try to click on any of the buttons at that point the code errors out with modal.modal('show') is not a function.

Is there a way to fix this so that I can open any of them via the created button, close them then open another one without refreshing the page?
`

I have tried moving the script within the page, I have tried sending info to the console and can get the Modal opens and the Modal closes but when I click on any link at that point it returns the same error.

Comment: I was able to recreate your issue here https://jsfiddle.net/jf9sw45v/26/ - as soon as I commented out the line `modal.find('.modal-content').empty()` inside the `hide.bs.modal` event, the modals started working properly. This can't be a perfect 1 to 1 match of your environment, so this may not be related to your problem. If that doesn't solve it, try to create your own JSFiddle with an example from your real code and maybe we can figure out something

Comment: It turns out the issue was in my button,  specifically I left out the target attributte data-bs-target  and also I used data-toggle instead of data-bs-toggle.  The code is now working as intended in terms of it opening and closing correctly.  Thank you for your assistance you gave me a different direction to look.